# How to iterate over modified files in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Don't you know if there's any way to iterate over modified files (according to git log) in Visual Studio Code without a mouse?

Usually before pushing my changes to VCS I loop thru the files to "approve" the changes of mine, maybe I left some TODO and forgot about it, or made some typo in one of the files. In IDEA the flow was:

- [by shortcut] Open a dialog with all the modified files
- [by shortcut] Open a diff view for a single file
- [by shortcut] Go to next / previous file

In VSCode, I currently do it like this:

- [by shortcut] Open a tab with Source Control
- **[by mouse]** Select the first file
- **[by mouse]** Select all the next files

In case of many files changed, it becomes ridiculous.
I failed to find a shortcut for such action in the settings though.

What is your way to accomplish that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> [by mouse] Select the first file

There is no native command to open the next file with changes.

The extension which would be the most likely to implement that is **[GitLens](https://gitlens.amod.io/)**.
A feature request exists: [issue 1237](https://github.com/gitkraken/vscode-gitlens/issues/1237)

> ### Commits view: add key-bindable command to "Open Changes On Next File"
>
> While browsing a commit's changes I currently need to click on each file to Open Changes.
> I want to suggest to create a new command to open changes on the next file in the commits view (eg, "`gitlens.views.commits.openChangesNextFile`"), so that this can be bound to a key and used to traverse the commit history more efficiently.

The same issue suggests:

> Instead, I would recommend creating a single command that goes to the next change, whether it is in the next file or not.
>
> VSCode currently has <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> for `workbench.action.editor.nextChange`, which goes to the next hunk of a editor diff.
>
> Perhaps the best UI Is to just hijack it and jump to the next file when we are the last change of a diff.
>
> Without this feature, I just can't let go of the terrible `git lop -p` + copy pasting paths from terminal into editor :-(
> But that is better than mouse clicking file by file as I only need to mouse click on the ones I'm interested in at least rather than doing it to see every new file (which on terminal is a <kbd>D</kbd> press away)